# visp wiki pages not working?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For some odd reason I can't seem to open the visp wiki pages, located here: http://wiki.ros.org/visp and here: http://wiki.ros.org/visp_auto_tracker .. The page seems to load the content and then disappears.

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236763/visp-wiki-pages-not-working?/) by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like something isn't completely right with those pages.

Afaict, each release-specific sub-page (ie: [visp/Jade](http://wiki.ros.org/visp/Jade), etc) contains a `PackageHeader(..)` macro invocation, which seems to cause the version rockers to be included on the page, but then the top page ([wiki/visp](http://wiki.ros.org/visp)) seems to use `include(..)` statements that are guarded by `wiki version(..)` macros. The combination of those two might be the reason things aren't quite working.

An alternative that's always worked for me is to create a top page with a single `PackageHeader(..)` and then the release-specific sub-pages only contain the rest of the information (so no `PackageHeader`s).

It's probably best to let the author/maintainer of `visp` know about this. I suggest you report an issue on the `visp` [issue tracker](https://github.com/lagadic/vision_visp/issues).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) on 2016-06-19**:
Posted in the VISP issue tracker. https://github.com/lagadic/vision_visp/issues/53